# Регулярное выражение: следующий символ после цифры

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть рабочая регулярка, которая возвращает название улицы, номер дома и квартиру: `(^.*?(?=\()|\d+)` для такой строки: `Анни Ярославни(Ц.-М.) вул. буд.1 кв.0` 
Но как ее модернизировать, что бы она вернула номер дома, если там будет еще и буква, аля `Анни Ярославни(Ц.-М.) вул. буд.1А кв.0` ?

Comment: (^.*?(?=\()|\w+) \w вместо \d

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick почему комментарий а не ответ?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick Не думаю что для адреса `\w` сгодится. дома все таки обычно с цифр начинаются. хотя допускаю конечно что где то могут быть только из букв, но скорее не в обычной городской застройке

Comment: думаю все таки `\d+[A-Za-z]?` будет уместней

Comment: @Mike да, только ещё кириллицу добавить надо \d+[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+

Comment: @Mike \w  я забыл, что ищет только в ANSI и для кириллицы не подойдёт

Comment: @Mike тогда не работает поиск квартиры https://regex101.com/r/eW4Sb2/2

Comment: @Nisu так  добавьте |\d+ в регулярку (^.*?(?=\()|\d+[A-Za-zА-Яа-я]+|\d+)

Comment: @Nisu Обратите внимание, я сказал `\d+[A-Za-z]?` вы вопросительный знак в конце не написали и получили букву обязательной

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick \w для кирилицы отлично подходит, когда регулярка в режиме UTF8. только тогда всякие китайские иероглифы то же попадут под нее, что видимо будет уже перебором

Comment: @Nisu Интересно, как вы собираетесь разбирать такой регуляркой адрес `марьиной рощи 3-й проезд 40с1`

Comment: @Mike хм... а вы можете предложить что-то другое тогда?

Comment: Особых предложений нет, просто регулярками такие вещи не делаются. нужен полный разбор текста. Видел готовые библиотеки на перле и подозреваю, что они не особо маленькие

Comment: Не нужно пытаться написать универсальную либу. Иногда, адрес просто  невозможно записать в подобных рамках. https://habrahabr.ru/company/friifond/blog/271733/ или https://habrahabr.ru/company/hflabs/blog/260601/

Comment: @Mike Кстати, при использовании, регулярка вроде букву и находит, но как кракозябру. В коде везде указан utf8, и при обращении к базе и при выводе на сайт. array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(22) "Біломорська" [1]=> string(3) "19�" [2]=> string(1) "0" } }

Comment: А вы в регулярке модификатор `u` поставили, что бы регулярка корректно utf8 понимала ?

Comment: Изначально он был, но почему-то при его использовании в var_dump строка дублируется, поэтому я его и убрал. А без него не работает utf8 - дилема =\

Answer (score 2):

Эта задача требует учёта довольно большого количества вариантов.

Попробуйте API Яндекс Геокодер (подойдёт, если работаете с существующими адресами). Он умеет из строки адреса вернуть удобный XML со всеми компонентами адреса.